# Translation of "ban" / Traduction de "ban"

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, littérature

What would be the most accurate translation of **ban**? The sentence is: "Tout le **ban**, le fin fond de la Critique, au sacré complet (...)".

I looked it up in the dictionary and **ban** could be understood as *ovation* or, if understood as an ellipsis of the expression *convoquer le ban et l'arrière-ban*, it could also be understood as *vassals*. The English translation (1954) of the above mentioned sentence, however, conceives **ban** as *whole works*: "The whole works, the dregs of criticism, out-and-out swearing (...)."

Which one would be the best translation of **ban** in this case?

Comment: The early and most basic meaning medieval seems to mean: A "call to arms" by a king or lord of their vassals. The word is left as in a historical context, It would be useful to have the sentence and author. I think that translation of ban you found is very bad.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The sentence was written by Louis-Ferdinand Céline (1944) : "Tout le ban, le fin fond de la Critique, au sacré complet, calotins, maçons, youtrons, rombiers et rombières, binocleux, chuchoteux, athlètes, gratte-culs, toute la Légion, toute là debout, hagarde, déconnante l'écume !"

Comment: An entire lot of liegemen, the very dregs of Critics///as in fin fond du pays, also, fond as bottom of a barrel. So dregs is good, but whole works I don't like since for me le ban refers to a whole group of vassals, who suck up to a lord or king. Also, critique here are more people than the criticism they produce. A great sentence, to be sure.

Comment: @Lambie So you see "calotins", "maçons" as liegemen kowtowing to a Ferdinand Céline?

Comment: @LPH No, I think the author's point of view, through, I presume, the character, is that the **character is saying** there is an assembly of a whole lot of people which he, the character, goes on to enumerate. What I was saying about ban is that **generally** vassals have to kowtow. He is describing the band of assembled people.

Comment: @Lambie That way it makes sense. The "character" is Céline speaking about his books: "'Mort à Crédit' fut accueilli, qu'on s'en rappelle, par un de ces tirs de barrage comme on n'avait pas vu souvent, d'intensité, de hargne et fiel ! Tout le ban,…". "Mort à crédit" is one of his works.

Comment: @LPH Not an author I have read.

Comment: @Lambie Here is a pdf you can leaf through or download if you want to get a better idea of what to expect: https://archive.org/details/GuignolsBand

Answer (score 1):

Il faut comprendre cela comme dans les expression contenant « *tout [le ban et l'arrière ban](https://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/40932)* », c'est à dire « tous ceux qui peuvent être concernés, au grand complet ».

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ban)) − P. anal., à l'époque mod. [Toujours associé à arrière-ban*] . Convoquer le ban et l'arrière-ban d'une famille, des amis ou des partisans.

L'expression n'est pas limitée à une utilisation avec « convoquer », comme le montrent les références, mais « et l'arrière ban » est toujours compris dans la locution, sauf chez Céline.

([réf.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Jusqu_ici_tout_va_bien/cmQiAQAAIAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22tout+le+ban%22&dq=%22tout+le+ban%22&printsec=frontcover))  Tout le ban et l ' arrière - ban des collaborateurs sont là pour remplir l ' espace devant les buffets garnis . Parmi les surprises du soir , cinq ou six UDF , pas plus , sont noyés dans la foule

([réf.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Guignol_s_band_I_Guignol_s_band_II_Le_po/aSJNAQAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22tout+le+ban%22&dq=%22tout+le+ban%22&printsec=frontcover)) Mort à Crédit fut accueilli, qu'on s'en rappelle, par un de ces tirs de
barrage comme on n'avait pas vu souvent, d'intensité, de hargne et fiel !
Tout le ban, le fin fond de la Critique, au sacré complet, calotins, maçons, youtrons, rombiers et rombières, binocleux, chuchoteux, athlètes, gratte-culs,
toute la Légion, toute là debout, hagarde, déconnante l'écume !

([réf.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Le_M%C3%A9nestrel/Bs0JAQAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22tout+le+ban%22&dq=%22tout+le+ban%22&printsec=frontcover)) Là - dessus , grand délire de la moitié environ de la salle , tout le ban et l'arrière - ban des wagnériens réunis ;

Il est probable que Céline a négligé l'expression traditionnelle et l'a raccourcie. La raison pour croire cela est que ce qui suit l'expression est une énumération  de tous les individus et courants d'opinion qui auraient pu constituer la critique ; l'expression « au sacré complet » est une autre confirmation de cette conclusion.

Comment: À votre avis, serait-il possible d'admettre une ambigüité du sens, par rapport au choix du mot ''ban'' ? Compte tenu de l'usage que fait Céline de l'expression originale et de l'ironie à l'égard des opinions exprimées par la critique.... qu'en pensez-vous ?

Comment: @AmandaFievet Non, j'ai relu l'introduction à _Guignol's band_, où se trouve cette phrase, et il n'y a pas d'allusion à ce contexte historique, ni de possibilité d'en faire.  À mon avis, il ne s'agit dans cet usage que d'ajouter un terme dans un schéma de simple rhétorique  pour insister sur l'ubiquité de la critique (le ban, au sacré complet, toute la Légion, toute là), ce schéma consistant en une accumulation de termes qui montrent l'universalité du phénomène.

Comment: Ce qui est sûr, c'est qu'il ne s'agit pas là d'un *ban bourguignon* ;-)